# Trend Function returning low values in Excel

Tags: excel, trend

I am trying to use the trend function to forecast sales based on past sales history. Each month of actual sales has returned a 6 figures value, but the trend output for the next month is returning a 5 figure value. With the last 6 months below, using formula TREND(A1:A6,B1:B6,B7) I'm getting  41,655.43

```
A         B
1   292509.8067
2   354164.0416
3   359780.7713
4   268131.6238
5   308061.3396
6   422070.879
7
```

Could anyone give me some advice with this? I don't understand how this is following the trend, it shouldn't drop so much.

Comment: Is there a value for 7 missing from your question?

Comment: 7 is the month I'm trying to forecast, my understanding is the TREND function should return an unknown X value for known Ys and Known Xs. It does return a value, but I don't understand why the trend is forecasting a drop from over 400k to 40k

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I mixed up the X and Y values which was causing the issue